# Разбить элементы списка на пары и сделать словарь

Tags: python, list, dict

Есть список:

```
['Hulk', 88, 'Thanos', 100, 'Captain America', 69]
```

Как мне из него сделать словарь такого вида:

```
{'Hulk': 88, 'Thanos': 100, 'Captain America': 69}
```

Answer (score 4):

Можно сделать при помощи срезов и функции `zip` (чтобы сгруппировать элементы списка)

```
lst = ['Hulk', 88, 'Thanos', 100, 'Captain America', 69]
dct = dict(zip(lst[::2], lst[1::2]))

print(dct) # {'Hulk': 88, 'Thanos': 100, 'Captain America': 69}
```

Comment: кстати либо data на lst, либо наоборот :)

Comment: @splash58 ой, спасибо!)

Answer (score 3):

можно порезать на пары генератором

```
dct = dict(a[x:x+2] for x in range(0, len(a), 2))
```

Comment: Так чуть похуже, потому что при нечетной длине списка будет ошибка

Comment: @Павел как то очень любопытно узнать ожидаемый результат при  нечетной длине :) Очень правильное прерывание будет

Comment: ну тут да, соглашусь, по-разному можно воспринять, я просто подумал, что возможно при неизвестном объеме входных данных логично делать пары из тех элементов, что друг для друга находятся, а если длина нечетная, то последний - не учитывать, но это скорее действительно какие-то невалидные данные тогда)